# Why Do I Get 'None' After Reverse()

Tags: python

Why do I get 'None' after I execute this code:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

list_2 = list_1.reverse()

print(list_2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `list_1.reverse()` is an inplace operation, which mean it modifies the existing list object instead of creating a new one

Comment: I know that but I don't understand why I can't reference list_1's new arrangement to list_2

Comment: either don't create a new list and just use `list_1.reverse()` or create the new list by `list(reversed(list_1))`

Answer (score 1):

`list_1.reverse()` returns `None`, but instead it reverses `list_1` itself.

In order to get a reversed result of `list_1`, you should do like this:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

list_2 = list_1.copy()
list_2.reverse()

print(list_2)
```